# When to register the "payment" event in Stripe webhook

Tags: stripe-payments

There is the following event from Stripe that shows a charge has went through:

```
charge.succeeded
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.succeeded

From this I can generate an invoice receipt and email it to the customer. Easy enough. However, there is zero information about what is charged in that item -- it only shows the amount. More importantly, it doesn't tell me when the subscription start/end is, which I need to tell the customer in the invoice receipt.

I need to get the different items in the subscription that were charged. It seems like I can use this item instead:

```
invoice.payment_succeeded
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded

This gives the items in the subscription and also the `amount_paid`, however it doesn't reference the `charge` object or anything. I'm also concerned that this event seems a bit more abstracted than the `charge.succeeeded/refunded` event, so it possibly may not capture anything (please correct me if I'm wrong).

For a subscription, which of the above two methods should I use to trigger when I send an invoice email? Why would one be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a subscription, which of the above two methods should I use to trigger when I send an invoice email? Why would one be preferred over the other?

You should prefer the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event, because as you noticed, it refers directly to the invoice from the subscription and thus has much more of the information that you would need to build a receipt email for the payment.

> however it doesn't reference the  charge object or anything

The event payload is an Invoice object, which has a [`charge`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-charge) field  with the charge ID for the most recent charge on the invoice(which will be what caused the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event to trigger). You can [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve) that charge to get further information from that if needed.

Comment: Great, this is super helpful. Also, thanks for pointing out the `charge` field, I missed that initially.